# How to delete a UIButton?

Tags: ios

I'm not able to delete the UIButton at the top left in the screen shot below. Please tell me how I can remove it completely.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Where to change Title style]

Here you can see where you need to change settings to avoid error about Plain Style

Comment: The error is still there even after I removed the UI Button

Comment: Try to clean project or maybe there is  another navigation item with plain style.

Answer (score 2):

Click this button, it will open up a hierarchy of all view controllers and UI elements:

[image]

When you click an element in the storyboard, it will be selected in the hierarchy as well. You can find the corresponding view controller, expand all the views, select the unwanted button and delete it.

Comment: Thank you! Also, would you have any idea on how to remove the Plain Style error that I'm getting (shown on the left)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Please check this one]

You have to delete the nav bar item not the button. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Just as addition:]

In code, if you have created an `IBOutlet`, you can do something like:

```
button.removeFromSuperview()
```